# Шаблоны документов Битрикс24

Tags: ms-word, шаблоны, битрикс24

Можно ли в шаблоне документа прописать что-то вроде
Пользовательского поля:
={CompanyRequisites} where {CompanyId = 123}
Понимаю что неверно составлено, кто подскажет, как это сделать?
Очень рассчитываю на любую помощь.
Надеюсь понятно написал.

Comment: Наверное что-то вроде: =if{{CompanyId = 123},{CompanyRequisites}} .Но как правильно написать?

Answer (score 0):

В шаблонах документов нельзя прописывать условия. Такая опция на сегодняшний день не поддерживается.
Если нужно подставить какое-то конкретное значение - можно при помощи бизнес-процесса/робота в каком-нибудь пользовательском поле требуемое значение вычислить, а затем это пользовательское поле подставить в шаблон